# What does foo[] mean in $this->foo[] in php

Tags: php, brackets

Is `foo[]` an array?

In the following code is an array element being assigned to `foo[]`? And is there an array key that is automatically associated with it?

```
$this->foo[] = 'hello world';
```

Comment: no this is same as pushing elements to array

Comment: that is a push. sadly.

Answer (score 1):

This is adding an element to the end of the `foo` array.

It's the same as using [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).